# Equations break due to Greek characters

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc

When I try to render an Rmarkdown equation like `$\sigma = 1$` it fails to render, and the resulting document contains only `$ =1$` in plaintext. Strangely, `$$ \sigma=1$$` renders normally, but of course that's different from an inline equation which is what I want.

I have the same problem in pandoc when I try something like `pandoc -o test.pdf test.md`. $$ works, $ breaks with error:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.59 \$ \sigma
```

Why is this?

Comment: `echo '$\sigma = 1$' | pandoc -o test.pdf` works fine for me with pandoc 2.6

Comment: If I do a simple `pdf_document` containing  $\sigma = 1$ it works fine.  So you're going to have to put together a minimal reproducible example showing what you're doing.

Comment: It seems like `$` is automatically escaped, while `$$` is preserved to switch to display math mode. Maybe this is a setting in your editor? What options do you run with pandoc? Specifically, see [Math Input](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math-input). You may be loading certain modules that necessarily escape a single-`$` in the input, but not `$$`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].